# Projective Geometry and Duality

Tags: projective-geometry, duality-theorems

On duality, what would be the dual of "coplanar points"?

Let's say $p_1, p_2, p_3 \in \mathbb{P}^3$ are coplanar points, *i.e.* they all belong to a plane $\pi$. If I want to "translate" this statement to its dual, how would I do it?

I know that, in $\mathbb{P}^3$, duals of points are planes and duals of planes are points. Would it be that the three planes $p_1^*, p_2^*, p_3^*$ intersect at the point $\pi^*$? (I use $L^*$ to represent the dual of a projective linear variety $L$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just replace every "point" with "plane" and vice versa:

"The three points $a,b,c$ lie on the plane $d$."

becomes:

"The three planes $a,b,c$ $\color{red}{lie~on}$ the point $d$."

Then fix the incidence relation (marked in red), because saying that the three planes "lie on" the same point sounds off:

"The three planes $a,b,c$ $\color{red}{intersect}$ at the point $d$."

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.